# I just Installed ubuntu 20.04 in my Dell Inspiron 3567 but i cannot change brightness or resolution

Tags: graphics, intel

I just Installed ubuntu 20.04 in my Dell Inspiron 3567 but i cannot change brightness or resolution. (Graphics shows llvmpipe LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) instead of intel graphics 620

Comment: can you add `dpkg -l | egrep 'intel|mesa'` to your question?
`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have additional drivers available for your video card on Software & Updates and switch to the alternate if available.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/tc/es/empresas/p/inspiron-15-3567-laptop/pd It has either Intel or AMD graphics, drivers for both are open-source, so nothing will show up in Additional Drivers. Only with Nvidia you're expected to see something there.

Comment: There were no additional drivers